# Running JS-code on AngularJS init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code that I need to run when my app is initiated, to connect to an API and obtain an accessToken.

Right now I have a solution where the code below runs in a separate **init.js** in which I bootstrap the angular app when that is done.

The problem is that I need to pass on the variables to use them in the AngularJS app, so the easiest thing would be if I could perform the same things as I do now within the AngularJS app before the first state is loaded.

Does anyone know how to do that?

```
(function () {
function appStart() {
//Get variables
var accessToken = 'ABC123';

//Init Angular App
//Right now the solution I am working with uses as separate init.js where this code runs
//angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
}

function genericError() {
console.error('Something went wrong');
}

TT.native.init()
.done(appStart)
.fail(genericError);
})();
```

Comment: Can you add a ng-init="init()" at your body tag in index.html?
Then have that init function in your main controller.

Comment: the problem is that you need to pass variable in angular app,isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can register your `accessToken` in order to resolve it later in controller

```
    function appStart() {
    //Get variables
    var accessToken = 'ABC123';

        angular.module('myApp').factory('accessToken', function () 
                                                                          {
                                                                           return accessToken ;
                                                                          });
```

#### SomeCtrl

```
window.app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope',  '$routeParams', '$location', 'accessToken' , 
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, accessToken) {
        //using token
```